# How do I make text conditionally appear during the ":active" state of a button but otherwise hidden?

Tags: css, button, behavior

I am using CSS buttons to create an image gallery in which the `:focus` state is used to enlarge each image when clicked and the ":active" state is used to display a description of the image when it is clicked again. When the button is unclicked, the description is hidden, and when the user clicks elsewhere, either the image returns to thumbnail size or a different image is enlarged. Here's my CSS:

```
div.img button{
-webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s, ease .25s;
transition: width 2s, height 2s, ease .25s;
  }

.mdT {
display:inline-block;
width:100px;
height:100px;
margin:2px;
border:0px;
outline:0px;
vertical-align:top;
background-color:inherit;
  }

  .mdT:focus {
width:500px;
height:500px;
background-position: left top;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-color: inherit;
  }

  .mdT:active {
margin-bottom: 25px;
  }

  .mdI1       {   background-image:url(01a.jpg);     }
  .mdI1:focus {   background-image:url(01.jpg);     }
  .mdI2       {   background-image:url(02a.jpg);     }
  .mdI2:focus {   background-image:url(02.jpg);   }
  .mdI3       {   background-image:url(03a.jpg);     }
  .mdI3:focus {   background-image:url(03.jpg);   }
  .mdI4       {   background-image:url(04a.jpg);     }
  .mdI4:focus {   background-image:url(04.jpg);   }
```

And here's my html:

```
<div class="img">
  <h2>Image Set 1</h2>
  <button class="mdT mdI1" ></button>
  <button class="mdT mdI2" ></button>
  <button class="mdT mdI3" ></button>
  <button class="mdT mdI4" ></button>
</div>
```

A few notes:

I'd like the image descriptions to appear within the space created by the `25px` margin during the `:active` state.

I will adjust the width and height of these elements later, once I get all the source images sorted out. For now I'm using placeholders resembling my StackOverflow profile pic, just to make sure they work.

Mainly I'm not sure what kind of code I need, where to put it, and how to adjust it so that it's unique to each button.

I'm fairly new to writing in computer languages so in your responses please assume I know absolutely nothing about what I'm doing. Thanks!

Comment: You should make a fiddle with working graphics, like from placekitten.com or something similar.

Comment: What's the problem with your current code?

Comment: Re Oriol: basically the issue is that I don't know how or where to add the image descriptions so that they function in the exact way I've specified (hidden except during the ":active" state, within the space created by the 25px margin that drops down). Should they go in the CSS code for the individual buttons? Should a placeholder be created in the CSS code for the individual buttons and the descriptions modified in the HTML body? etc.

Comment: @jmargolisvt How's this? https://jsfiddle.net/CRpvr/112/

I seem to have made a little bit of progress but now I can't seem to get the text in the '<span>' to show up. I want it sort of "hidden" behind the image until the button is ':active', and then to show up in the space created by the margin in that state.

Comment: More progress: https://jsfiddle.net/CRpvr/114/ Now I've got the z-index all ready to go for when I get the text to behave the way I want. Still can't seem to make it stick to the bottom edge of the buttons.

Comment: There are a lot of other improvements you can make to your code to make it more readable and debuggable.  Firstly, you want `div`'s not buttons.  And you want classes to be reusable, so all these one-off classes are unsemantic.  Further, your choice of class name is unclear.  What is mdI5?  And using a tag name as a class name (using "img" as a class name) is also bad practice.  Try cleaning your fiddle up, maybe reducing it to just the one piece of code we need to test only and you'll attract more help.  Starting with clean and correct HTML is always helpful.

Comment: @jmargolisvt thanks for the responses. A few things, in order:
1. If I use 'div's will I still be able to get the same results from clicking as 'active' and 'focus' with buttons?
2. The weird name classes are the result of me copying-pasting code from elsewhere. Remember, I'm new to this, so I'm building code largely by copying-pasting and modifying only the parts I comprehend. My safe assumption was that the weird class names were necessary somehow.
3. I'm eager to hear back re point #1. Maybe at that point I'll do a fresh post with clearer code.

Comment: Yes, you get the same pseudo classes.  Good tip for learning: if you don't get it, *go read about it*. It's hard to debug code when there are a lot of parts you don't understand.  Start with simple stuff and add on as you learn new things.  Good luck!  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes

Comment: @jmargolisvt Thanks for confirming about the 'div' pseudo classes. Technically you could probably respond to every single post on this website with "Go read about it", so please know that in conjunction with the specific help I'm getting here, I'm doing my best to read up (largely on w3schools.com) and understand what I'm doing. As this develops, should I continue in this thread or start a new question?